# LightningChart stops updating when in background

Tags: lightningchart

Does anyone know how to prevent LightningChart from slowing down, almost pausing when the window displaying a constantly updating chart (e.g. a live data stream) is in the background?

For example, if I switch browser windows for any length of time, the chart seem to slow or stop updating altogether.

I am using LightningChart via Javascript in Safari, Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Thank you!
T

I've tried keeping the window open on its own (i.e. not opening new tabs within that window). With no success so far

Comment: Could you confirm if the chart is visible or not when it is slowing down?

Comment: the chart is not visible (e.g. when I switch to another application)

Comment: I would say this is expected behavior as far as I'm aware, since LCJS applications are often quite performance demanding and there is no reason to spend performance on a process that is not visible. Maybe you can elaborate why this is a problem in your situation?

Comment: That is usually a great feature, however in this case I don't want it to stop updating /slow down when in the background---  is there a way to turn this feature off that you know of?

Comment: Not that I know of. Would appreciate knowing the motivations why its bad if it doesn't update in the background in your case, so we can consider the priorities of this suggestion. I'm one of the developers of LCJS which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Hi Niilo! In my use case, I am looking at real-time data over a long period of time and want to have that window that is monitoring that open at all times on the computer. The issue is, whenever I use another program, window etc. on the computer the real-time data window running lightningchart has slowed down and is now behind in time.   I hope that explanation makes sense!

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's up exactly, but here are some ideas you can try:
- have you considered wrapping the web app into a desktop app using Electron?
- you can try forcing the chart to re-render with something like: setInterval(() => chart.engine.layout(), 1000/60) Note that this has obvious effects on performance as the chart is never resting even if no data points are coming in.

Comment: Hi Nililo,  I have it in a web-based app currently.  The chart.engine.layout method doesn't seem to work.

Do you have some sample code you could provide to show this working format?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, in this case I have nothing else to suggest. Perhaps there is no way to force charts re-rendering when they are in a non-focused browser tab. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem like a generally considerable limitation. Maybe you can elaborate further why it is important?